# Using a Kotlin object in a class generated at runtime

Tags: spring, kotlin, byte-buddy

I am using ByteBuddy to rebase a class of another library in order to add Spring dependency injection to it. The problem is that I can't instantiate the class that is used as the interceptor, which means that I can't use Spring to inject the `ApplicationContext` into the interceptor.

To get around this, I created an object `StaticAppContext`, which gets the `ApplicationContext` injected by implementing `ApplicationContextAware`:

```
@Component
object StaticAppContext : ApplicationContextAware {
    private val LOGGER = getLogger(StaticAppContext::class)

    @Volatile @JvmStatic lateinit var context: ApplicationContext

    override fun setApplicationContext(applicationContext: ApplicationContext?) {
        context = applicationContext!!
        LOGGER.info("ApplicationContext injected")
    }
}
```

This is getting injected just fine (I can see the log message), but when I try to access the `ApplicationContext` from the interceptor, I get `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property context has not been initialized`.

The class that rebases the class and the incerceptor are defined in this class:

```
package nu.peg.discord.d4j

import net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.ClassFileLocator
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.SuperMethodCall
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.*
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers
import net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool
import nu.peg.discord.config.BeanNameRegistry.STATIC_APP_CONTEXT
import nu.peg.discord.config.StaticAppContext
import nu.peg.discord.util.getLogger
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import sx.blah.discord.api.IDiscordClient
import sx.blah.discord.modules.Configuration
import sx.blah.discord.modules.IModule
import sx.blah.discord.modules.ModuleLoader
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor
import java.util.ArrayList
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct

/**
 * TODO Short summary
 *
 * @author Joel Messerli @15.02.2017
 */
@Component @DependsOn(STATIC_APP_CONTEXT)
class D4JModuleLoaderReplacer : IModule {
    companion object {
        private val LOGGER = getLogger(D4JModuleLoaderReplacer::class)
    }

    @PostConstruct
    fun replaceModuleLoader() {
        val pool = TypePool.Default.ofClassPath()

        ByteBuddy().rebase<Any>(
                pool.describe("sx.blah.discord.modules.ModuleLoader").resolve(), ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.ofClassPath()
        ).constructor(
                ElementMatchers.any()
        ).intercept(
                SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE.andThen(MethodDelegation.to(pool.describe("nu.peg.discord.d4j.SpringInjectingModuleLoaderInterceptor").resolve()))
        ).make().load(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION)

        LOGGER.info("The D4J ModuleLoader has been replaced with ByteBuddy to allow for Spring injection")
    }

    override fun getName() = "Spring Injecting Module Loader"
    override fun enable(client: IDiscordClient?) = true
    override fun getVersion() = "1.0.0"
    override fun getMinimumDiscord4JVersion() = "1.7"
    override fun getAuthor() = "Joel Messerli <hi.github@peg.nu>"
    override fun disable() {}
}

class SpringInjectingModuleLoaderInterceptor {
    companion object {
        private val LOGGER = getLogger(SpringInjectingModuleLoaderInterceptor::class)

        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        @JvmStatic
        fun <T> intercept(
                @This loader: ModuleLoader,
                @Origin ctor: Constructor<T>,
                @Argument(0) discordClient: IDiscordClient?,

                @FieldValue("modules") modules: List<Class<out IModule>>,
                @FieldValue("loadedModules") loadedModules: MutableList<IModule>
        ) {
            LOGGER.debug("Intercepting $ctor")
            val loaderClass = loader.javaClass
            val clientField = loaderClass.getDeclaredField("client")
            clientField.isAccessible = true
            clientField.set(loader, discordClient)

            val canModuleLoadMethod = loaderClass.getDeclaredMethod("canModuleLoad", IModule::class.java)
            canModuleLoadMethod.isAccessible = true

            val factory = StaticAppContext.context.autowireCapableBeanFactory
            for (moduleClass in modules) {
                try {
                    val wired = factory.autowire(moduleClass, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, false) as IModule
                    LOGGER.info("Loading autowired module {}@{} by {}", wired.name, wired.version, wired.author)
                    if (canModuleLoadMethod.invoke(loader, wired) as Boolean) {
                        loadedModules.add(wired)
                    } else {
                        LOGGER.info("${wired.name} needs at least version ${wired.minimumDiscord4JVersion} to be loaded (skipped)")
                    }
                } catch (e: BeansException) {
                    LOGGER.info("Spring could not create bean", e)
                }
            }

            if (Configuration.AUTOMATICALLY_ENABLE_MODULES) { // Handles module load order and loads the modules
                val toLoad = ArrayList<IModule>(loadedModules)

                val loadModuleMethod = loaderClass.getDeclaredMethod("loadModule", IModule::class.java)
                while (toLoad.size > 0) {
                    toLoad.filter { loadModuleMethod.invoke(loader, it) as Boolean }.forEach { toLoad.remove(it) }
                }
            }
            LOGGER.info("Module loading complete")
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug this, IntelliJ shows that a new instance of StaticAppContext is created when the interceptor tries to access the `StaticAppContext`, which makes sense since the exception is thrown.

Are Kotlin objects not really Singletons when called from generated code or am I doing something wrong? What would be a way to work around this?

The project can also be found on Github: https://github.com/jmesserli/discord-bernbot/tree/master/src/main/kotlin/nu/peg/discord

---

**Edit**
I was able to fix the problem by removing `spring-boot-devtools` which add their own `ClassLoader`. When I tried the suggestion to use `Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader`, I got a different exception telling me that it was already loaded by a different `ClassLoader` (which confirms that it was a problem with the `ClassLoader`s). Also, it seems that the assumption that there might be a race was correct.

I am having a different problem now, I'll do some research to see if I can solve it myself.

Answer (score 1):

A Kotlin `object` is compiled to the following layout:

```
public final class StaticAppContext {
  public static final StaticAppContext INSTANCE;
  private StaticAppContext();
  static {}
}
```

The class is implicitly a singleton. I do therefore wonder if the problem is a race in class loading. There is a good chance that the static initializer was already called. Are you sure that you are getting the correct log messages?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I'm a hobby programmer and have not worked with Spring yet. There's a bunch of speculation here based on what I *heard* about Spring.

---

I have a hunch this might be a classloader problem - you may have 2 `StaticAppContext` classes loaded in 2 different classloaders due to your usage of `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` in `D4JModuleLoaderReplacer.replaceModuleLoader()`.

To confirm this, log creation of the `StaticAppContext` object in an `init { ... }` block. Example:

```
@Component
object StaticAppContext : ApplicationContextAware {
    private val LOGGER = getLogger(StaticAppContext::class)

    init {
        LOGGER.info("StaticAppContext created. Classloader: ${javaClass.classLoader}")
    }

    ...
}
```

If my theory is right, you should get 2 creation log messages.

If this is the case, I believe you should use the current context classloader (`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`) instead.